# Why does `set_index` create an index label for the column name?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a CSV file which begins like this:

```
Year,Boys,Girls
1996,333490,315995
1997,329577,313518
1998,325903,309998
```

When I read it into pandas and set an index, it isn't doing quite what I expect:

```
df = pd.read_csv('../data/myfile.csv')
df.set_index('Year', inplace=True)
df.head()
```

Why is there an index entry for the column label, with blank values next to it? Shouldn't this simply disappear?

[image]

Also, I'm not clear on how to retrieve the values for 1998. If I try `df.loc['1998']` I get an error: `KeyError: 'the label [1998] is not in the [index]'`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should set the name attribute of your index to `None`:

```
df.index.names = [None]
df.head()
#       Boys    Girls
#1996   333490  315995
#1997   329577  313518
#1998   325903  309998
```

As for retrieving the data for `1998`, simply lose the quotes:

```
df.loc[1998]
#Boys     325903
#Girls    309998
#Name: 1998, dtype: int64
```